# How do i make a download button that appears after 5 seconds with countdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, http

im making a website and i want to protect my downloads so people don't download all the time.

I need a code that makes a button appear after 5 seconds.
I also need the codes to the scripts (Like JQuery) because i cant find them anywhere on the web
Or its just that i cant find them because im from holland?
Please i need help :)
I found one from JSFiddle but it didnt have the codes of JQuery in it and i really dont know where to find them.
By the way im using bootstrap! http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a Timeout function

**Javascript:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var button =  document.getElementById('test');
    button.style.display = "";}
    , 5000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="test" style="display:none">Download</button>
```

---

***After your comment, to set a countdown on the button, look at this:***

**new HTML:**

```
<button id="test" disabled>Download</button>
```

**new Javascript:**

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("test");
var counter = 5;

downloadButton.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 5 seconds.";
var id;



id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        downloadButton.innerHTML = "Download";
        downloadButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        downloadButton.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ub9vbu8/)

Comment: Thanks, this one worked, can you also write a script it counts down on a button?

Comment: Now the button didnt appear :O

Comment: You have to delete display:none in your css / inline style, will be made automatically

Comment: Well everyone dislikes it :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help.

HTML:

```
<div class="button">button</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.button').fadeIn(1000);
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Oki let me try this :D